# "Connection interrupted" after a few seconds of fighting the Ancients

Tags: diablo-ii

I'm being kicked from the game when fighting Ancients after about ten seconds of fighting them. Other than that, the game works fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: I didn't read the tag and I thought you were talking about Diablo 3's DRM. :P

Comment: Didn't know there were ancients in D3.

Comment: They aren't.  I think I caught "Diablo" as I was reading the title.

Comment: Anyway, on topic.  What exactly were you doing?  Anything in particular you were doing?  Are you an assassin and using Cloak of Shadows?

Comment: Yes, I am both of those things. Is it that bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found [this post on DiabloWiki forum](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/17808-compiled-list-of-assassin-bugs-issues-and-hopes-for-113/) with description of the bug with the Ancients, where using Cloak of Shadows can crash the game in Single player, but it appears to also do the job on Battle.net.